# Root Transform Position/Rotation option not showing up in Animation tab of fbx file

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 3d, fbx

[image: This is how I would like it to be]

[image: This is what shows up]

[image: Here's the Model tab]

[image: And Here's the Rig tab]

The First Image is how I would like it to be but it imports like the second image, is there any way this can be solved from Unity and not a third party 3D software?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

[From here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/no-root-transform-rotation-or-position-option-available-in-fbx-inspector.309523/?_ga=2.80833109.312537173.1613179782-1019417522.1610985501)

> Well, in case anyone would have the same issue: it came from the model
> used to create the avatar set in the fbx. In the Rig panel, Root node
> was set to None instead of the root of the model itself. After
> changing it, then clicking Update in the Rig panel of the animations
> fbx, the desired options came back.